# Dash (Flask App) Runs so much faster on my local than on Azure App Services

Tags: python, azure, flask, plotly-dash

I've deployed my Dash Flask app to my companies Azure environment through App Services.  At first, the initial load time was taking forever so I upgraded to Basic Tier and turned on "Always On".

Now the initial load time is instant, but the interactivity response times via all of my call backs (drop down selections, filters, check boxes etc) are like 5x slower than how it behaves on my local.

Is there anything else that I can do under Basic Tier, or app services in general, to help speed things up?

Comment: Facing a somewhat similar issue, where Azure randomly doesn't respond to some interactions on the Dash app. It works again if I reclick.